# UserControl is blank when added to panel (sometimes)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an App written in .Net Framework 4.7.2 that sporadically, when a new user control is needed to be added to a flow panel, it's added successfully (and bumped to the top of the panel), but the user control is blank. Here's how I create it:

```
int shortcutNumber = NextShortcutNumber();
ctrlIssue newIssueCtrl = new ctrlIssue(issueData, shortcutNumber);
        
newIssueCtrl.IssueDeleted += new System.EventHandler(this.ctrlIssue_IssueDeletedHandler);
newIssueCtrl.Visible = false;
panIssues.Controls.Add(newIssueCtrl);
panIssues.Controls.SetChildIndex(newIssueCtrl, 0);  // Always put it at the top
newIssueCtrl.Visible = true;
newIssueCtrl.Target();
```

I've diagnosed it down to that Control.Created is set to false. So ControlCreated is not called? I'm trying a workaround now like so:

```
if (!newIssueCtrl.Created)
{
    newIssueCtrl.CreateControl();
}
```

We'll see if it works, but it's weird. Does anyone have any insight on why ControlCreated wouldn't be called? It seems sporadic and inconsistent, when it starts happening, it happens about 80% of the time.

Thanks!

EDIT: There was an ask to see the ctrlIssue constructor. There's fancy in it:

```
    public ctrlIssue(Issue data, int shortcut)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        mIssueData = data;
        chkPlayPause.TabIndex = 2;
        lblProject.Text = mIssueData.Fields.Project.Name;
        chkPlayPause.Text = mIssueData.Key;
        lblSummary.Text = mIssueData.Fields.Summary;

        InitializeToolTips();
        UpdateShortcut(shortcut);

        mSummaryFontRegular = lblSummary.Font;
        mSummaryFontHover = new Font(mSummaryFontRegular, FontStyle.Underline);
        mProjectFontRegular = lblProject.Font;
        mProjectFontHover = new Font(mProjectFontRegular, FontStyle.Underline);
    }
```

Comment: Is the constructor completing (new ctrlIssue(issueData, shortcutNumber);)  You may have an exception in the constructor.  The object base class is called after the constructor completes which finalizes the object.  So you have to make sure the constructor finishes.

Comment: Remove those `.Visible = false / .Visible = true` things and post the UC's Constructor. Not clear when/where you check `newIssueCtrl.Created` and why you want to call `CreateControl()` when `.Created = true` (unless you forgot a `!`)

Comment: @jdweng - thanks for the tip, I'll put a log in there and see what's happening.

Comment: Yeah sorry @Jimi, that was a goof, was supposed to be !newIssueCtrl.Created. I'll update the OG post.

Comment: The are some properties you set in a constructor.  After a constructor runs there are methods in the base class that run to complete the constructor.  So in some cases you need to also have a load method.  I'm suspecting you may be getting an exception.  Try stepping through the code.  Put a break point after the InitializeComponent().  Another thing to check are events.  You could be getting an event before the constructor completes.  The events are set in the InitializeComponent().  The you have to add checks in the event to prevent exceptions.